# CodeMagic : Building iOS error : Module not found

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to build my flutter app using codemagic.

I got this error

```
 /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:30:9: fatal error: module 'hexcolor' not found
@import hexcolor;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

If I check the dependencies I can see that the module **hexcolor** was downloaded.

```
Downloading shimmer_animation 2.1.0+1...
Downloading json_annotation 4.6.0...
Downloading hexcolor 2.0.7...
Downloading google_fonts 3.0.1...
```

How can I fix this ? It's the first time I use codemagic and the first time I build my flutter app for IOS.
Any help will be appreciated .

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Check your iOS version **xcode** and **pod file** matches properly

Comment: Thank you ! I adapted the version and it's fixed

Comment: can you explain what exactly you did in codemagic or in the flutter project to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my flutter sdk version in my local machine, then regenerated ios files using the commande `flutter create .` then pushed the code

Then rebuild ios and it works

I don't have to check my iOS version xcode and pod file matches properly, cus it is flutter sdk responsibility to make them matching, all I have to is upgrade flutter sdk